# Making a basic GUI for a Java 'Connect Four' game

Tags: java, user-interface

This might be either a too basic and a too huge question to ask.

Although I study business management as my discipline, by some chance I am taking a Java module this year and am currently working on building a 'Connect Four' game. So far, I have succeeded making the game work in the console, however, I have utterly no idea about how to present the game through GUI. I mean, I could build a GUI window in a separate class but could you help me extending the class methods I created before to the GUI class that I don't have to write the whole programme again? Many thanks.

All of the codes I wrote are here: https://github.com/aca16kd/java-connect-four/tree/master/Assignment/src. The classes live in assignment2017 folder as well as the main class, PlayConnect4, and the EasyReader class which could be used as exactly same as java.util.Scanner lives in sheffield folder.

Comment: This is a very broad question, and lots of tutorials can be found if you simply do some Googling. I'd recommend taking a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm to introduce you to creating a GUI with Swing/JavaFX. In the future, please do some research before posting a question.

Comment: I'm not sure what would qualify as an answer to this question.  What kind of help are you expecting here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way (I can think of) is having a separate GUI class which extends Jframe and implements Action Listeners. This way you could have a simple text box in a frame with a couple of buttons.